# Create tansparent activity over lockscreen without setting windowIsTranslucent

Tags: android, android-activity, transparent, lockscreen, activity-lifecycle

I am creating a transparent activity over lockscreen by setting `windowIsTranslucent` to true in the `themes` directory.

When this transparent activity is launched over any activity, I am seeing the following error log:

```
E/ActivityThread: Performing stop of activity that is already stopped
```

[This is a similar issue on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51536494/windowistranslucent-changes-lifecycle-but-error-occur-when-entering-lock-screen) - Still hasn't worked for me.

Is there any other way to create a transparent activity in android without setting `windowIsTranslucent` in the `theme` directory since it has unexpected lifecycle events?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120558902